# jQuery Auto Refresh Can't Function

Tags: jquery

I want to pass content variable using ID in my jQuery Auto Refresh div.

Here is the JS :

```
$(function () {
    $("#refresh").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var part_no = $("#part_no").val();

        $('.randomdiv').load('result_data_revision.php', {
            part_no: part_no
        });
    });        
});
```

and PHP :

```
<?php echo $part_no = $_GET['part_no']; ?>
```

Now facing problem, the div is not refresh. Please help to advice?

Thanks

Comment: Semicolons are missing in two lines after evt.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks, now how can I pass the part_no content to the PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put your data label into quotes, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $("#refresh").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var part_no = $("#part_no").val();

        $('.randomdiv').load('result_data_revision.php', {
            "part_no": part_no
        });
    });        
});
```

The JS will replace the part_no with its value before sending and therefore send it with a changing key.

Edit:
Secondly the data that is provided using `.load()` is a POST request so you might find your data like:

```
<?php echo $part_no = $_POST['part_no']; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $part_no = $_REQUEST['part_no']; ?>
```

Alternatively you could create a GET request like so:

```
 $(function () {
    $("#refresh").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var part_no = $("#part_no").val();

        $('.randomdiv').load('result_data_revision.php?part_no='+part_no);
    });        
});
```

jQuery will handle the URL-enconding in this case, too.

Hope this helps.